Delete certain files from specific date in linux
I need a command how I can delete files from a folder with specific date.
Like I want to delete files before 20 April from a folder on /home/FTP and file types are mp4.

This option "-mtime +12" specifies the modification time of the files.
Here, +12 means files modified more than 12 days ago. Since you want to delete files before 20th April and today is 2nd May, that's 12 days ago.
find /home/FTP -name "*.mp4" -type f -mtime +12 -delete


Thanks .. i will try this and will update you. Really appreciate it

Sir one thing, what if i want to delete files on certain date like  2 April's . Mp4 files. Then what command i will have to use? Please help

-mtime +12 matches on files whose age rounded down to an integer number of 24 hour units is strictly greater than 12, so 13 or more. So if run at 2024-05-02T13:00:00.000, it will find files last-modified at or before 2024-04-19T13:00:00.000. You'd need -daystart -mtime +12 (-daystart being a non-standard extension) for files last modified before 2024-04-20T00:00:00 or find . ! newermt 2024-04-20T00:00:00 with some find implementations (usually the same as those that support -daystart).

You can probably use the -newer with an inversion and a reference file
You first create a reference file dated with your date (in this case 20th of April 2024 at midnight)
touch -d "2024-04-20 00:00:00" /tmp/reference

Then you launch a find using this reference and an "not"
find /yourfolder/ -type f -name "*.mp4" ! -newer /tmp/reference

This should display the files you want to delete.
If the result is what you are looking for, then add -delete at the end of your find.
